# How to make a shortcut key for a button

Tags: c#, winforms

i am now working on making c# window forms app.

and i have trouble making shortcut keys.

[image]

above picture is a part of property  of button1 named 'Generator'.

i want to make shortcut key (Alt + '1') to that button.

I know if i write text part as '&1Generator', it works,

but it looks weird to me.

i just want to show 'Generate' text on that button

anyone please help me to fix it. thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [`ProcessCmdKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.processcmdkey(v=vs.110).aspx) in the `form` and handle the shortcut there.
A possible implementation in your case might look like this:

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
{
    if (keyData == (Keys.Alt | Keys.D1))
    {
        this.button1.PerformClick();
    }

    return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ShortcutKeys` property for `MenuItem`.

Add `MenuStrip` to form, if no any. Add `MenuItem`. Set `ShortcutKeys` to `Alt+1` value. In `MenuItem_Click` write:

```
buttonGenerate.PerformClick();
```

It must work.

If you don't need a menu or concrete menu item, you can hide it by setting the property `Visible = true`.